# Would this battery/solar powered esp32 weather station work?

Tags: arduino, batteries, solar-cell, esp32

I am trying to design a circuit that runs an esp32 with a dh11 sensor but i am unsure if it would work.

- On the top left is a mcp73831-5-OT li ion battery charging chip (the random wire on the left is 5v in from the solar panel)
- On the top right is the AMS1117 3.3v variant regulator (picked it for the tiny package and availabilty)
- On the bottom left is a esp32 module and its accompanying circuitry (im really suspicious abou that circuit though)
- On the bottom right is a dht11 connected to power and data with its accompanying pull up

So,if i build this,would it work? If not,what should i change?

[image: da schematic]

Comment: You haven't given details of what you are suspicious about.

Comment: @Andyaka I got the esp32 schematic from a unofficial source so i would like to verify if its gonna work. Also i am currently new to batteries so it would be nice to verify that too.

Comment: Have you tried looking at official sources? If not why not?

Comment: Probably not.  You certainly don't want to use as high quiescent a regulator as the AMS1117.  Designing this kind of thing is *hard* and typically requires a lot more consideration of details.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I was thinking of putting a large 4000mah battery so quiscent isnt as important as availabilty

Comment: @ChrisStratton Is there anything about it that simply won't work? this thing has all the conditions going for it.  A large battery,not being a bare pcb,a ton of space...etc

Comment: If you're not going to start by making efficient choices in the case of something easy like the regulator where there are alternatives, then you are following an approach with a very low likelihood of success.  The actually hard parts of the project haven't event entered into the thinking yet.

Comment: Define "work". Do you have any expectations for running time off that battery? Have you written up a power budget?

Comment: @BrianDrummond I believe it consume around 40.8mA,so i expect it to last for a bit. Correct me if im wrong though. That seems normal considering a average devkit consumes the same amount. That should allow it to stay on for at least 10 hours

Comment: @BrianDrummond but thats on single core mode

Comment: Instead of dribbling out details in comments, add them to the question. From two comments so far, at 40 mA you have nominal 100h life so your 10 hour "requirement" looks good. Four cloudy days and you may be in trouble, but you haven't suggested that's a problem. But you may want to monitor battery life (perhaps Vbatt bearing in mind it's not linear) and enforce "single core mode" or low power operation below some value.

Comment: No, it won't work. DHT11 would blow up, double check the power connections to it. Also it makes me wonder why are you not using the datasheet suggested resistor value, is there a special reason to deviate from suggested value, and what would be that reason?

Comment: @Justme oh lol thanks for pointing that out im really an idiot

Comment: @BrianDrummond It's a rather simple project so i dont believe single core mode is neccesary,maybe i could set it up to slow down the refresh rate

Comment: What location? See http://www.gaisma.com for insolation data.