# Would this silary battery shield work?

Tags: arduino, components, solar-cell, low-power, hardware

I am making an open source solar battery shield for the Arduino Uno, would this circuit work? It's pretty basic but I think it would do the trick.

Also,the power from the solar cell will come into the AMS1117-5.0 for positive and gnd for negative.

PS: Yes, I know that I'm supposed to connect the EN pin of the 3.3V reg to Vin.

[image: image of schematic]

Comment: Are there any parts you are worried/unsure about?

Comment: This question seems to exhibit the same problems as your previous one https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/524532/would-this-battery-solar-powered-esp32-weather-station-work and actually appears to be your third question of this type - rather than again asking an open-ended "will this work" consider the issues raised there, and pursue the path of resolving them at your **existing question**  And why are you still using that AM1117?

Comment: 1) What is "silary battery shield"? 2) *would this circuit work?* Don't ask "will this work" when you don't tell us **what it is supposed to do**. 3) The schematic is drawn in a "messy" way and that immediately makes me doubt that it is a good design. The LTC3525 has no connection on Vout. => so **no, this will not work**. Look at the LTC3525's datasheet, there's an application diagram there, just re-draw your circuit to make it look identical. There is no reason to place the 1uF cap above the IC.

Comment: There is no signal connected to VI of the AMS1117. Vi/Reset/IOREF on the connector all go nowhere. I don't see a DC input voltage to the LTC3525. Is Battery-out shorted to GND over the LTC3525? LTC3525 SHDNb pin is not connected.

Comment: Can you capitalise brand names, etc., properly for legibility and clarity? It makes the title and content much clearer. Capitals matter!

Comment: @ChrisStratton I'm still learning how to properly use batteries. Also, the am1117 in this schematic was newly added and is only for regulating the input from the panel to the charger,so efficiency is not a big deal

Comment: Is this circuit diagram correct? I don't think so.. there are lots of pins unconnected!!